# usar Using en Mongo C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

hola necesito hacer una especie de **`using`** en partes de un código que estoy depurando

tengo una linea de código:

```
maintenancesCollection.ReplaceOne(filterId, bsonData, new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });
```

pero esta no cierra la conexión y necesito que me libere hilos, para hacer unas actualizaciones en estas lineas...

```
var filterId = new BsonDocument("_id", line.Id);
var updateLine = new BsonDocument("$set", BsonData);
linesCollection.UpdateOne(filterId, updateLine);
```

en esta también se necesita que se tenga un **`using`**, ya que en en otro método de la clase donde se tienen estas instrucciones se necesita un `deleteMany`

a otras colecciones.

**EDICION**
Los errores que me salen en las lineas UpdateOne, ReplaceOne y DeleteMany

> en MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelper(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      en MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.Open(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      en MongoDB.Driver.Core.ConnectionPools.ExclusiveConnectionPool.AcquiredConnection.Open(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      en MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.Server.GetChannel(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      en MongoDB.Driver.Core.Bindings.ServerChannelSource.GetChannel(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      en MongoDB.Driver.Core.Bindings.ChannelSourceHandle.GetChannel(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      en MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.RetryableWriteContext.Create(IWriteBinding binding, Boolean retryRequested, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      en MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.BulkMixedWriteOperation.Execute(IWriteBinding binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      en MongoDB.Driver.OperationExecutor.ExecuteWriteOperation[TResult](IWriteBinding binding, IWriteOperation`1 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      en MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.ExecuteWriteOperation[TResult](IClientSessionHandle session, IWriteOperation`1 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      en MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.BulkWrite(IClientSessionHandle session, IEnumerable`1 requests, BulkWriteOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      en MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.b__0(IClientSessionHandle session)
>      en MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSession[TResult](Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      en MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.BulkWrite(IEnumerable`1 requests, BulkWriteOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      en MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionBase`1.<>c__DisplayClass94_0.<UpdateOne>b__0(IEnumerable`1 requests, BulkWriteOptions bulkWriteOptions)
>      en MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionBase`1.UpdateOne(FilterDefinition`1 filter, UpdateDefinition`1 update, UpdateOptions options, Func`3 bulkWrite)
>      en MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionBase`1.UpdateOne(FilterDefinition`1 filter, UpdateDefinition`1 update, UpdateOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      en DataManager.UpdateElements.<>c__DisplayClass82_0.b__0(Line line)

Comment: Pero cual seria el problema? esos objetos no soportan using? no tienen close o dispose?

Comment: @gbianchi el problema es que sale muchos errores como     este en 
MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.BulkWrite(IClientSessionHandle session, IEnumerable`1 requests, BulkWriteOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   en MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<BulkWrite>b__0(IClientSessionHandle session)
   en MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSession[TResult]
 supongo que es porque no cierra conexiones y utiliza muchos hilos.

Comment: Si salen errores, pone los errores completos en la pregunta y cuando ocurren asi podemos ayudarte mejor.